# Getting 'Rich Embed fields may not be empty' error when my code works

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a piece of code that logs if someone has edited their message. It works perfectly, it shows the old message, the new one, the channel and more. But, I still get an error that says that my RichEmbed fields are empty. They aren't empty and they work! The error apparently occurs on line 198 - `.addField('Original:',`${oldMessage.content}`)`

This is for a bot I am making for Discord. I can't find any help anywhere.

Here is my code:

```js
bot.on('messageUpdate', async(oldMessage, newMessage) => {
    const emb8 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(':pencil: Message Edited')
    .setDescription('A user has edited a message.')
    .addField('Guild:', `${newMessage.guild.name}`)
    .addField('User:', `${newMessage.author.tag}`)
    .addField('Original:', `${oldMessage.content}`)
    .addField('Edited to:', `${newMessage.content}`)
    .addField('Channel:', `<#${newMessage.channel.id}>`)
    .addField('Time:', `${newMessage.createdAt}`)
    .setColor(0xFF9800)
    .setFooter('Sublime | Logs', 'https://file.coffee/WdTuqTwGF.PNG')
    bot.channels.get(`603943993348325392`).send(emb8)
});
```

It looks exactly how I want it to look, but for some reason I get this error:

> js (node:162592) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError:
>   RichEmbed field values may not be empty.
>       at RichEmbed.addField (E:\Sublime-Project\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\RichEmbed.js:166:34)
>       at CommandoClient.bot.on (E:\Sublime-Project\index.js:193:3)
>       at CommandoClient.emit (events.js:202:15)
>       at MessageUpdateAction.handle (E:\Sublime-Project\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageUpdate.js:13:16)
>       at MessageUpdateHandler.handle (E:\Sublime-Project\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageUpdate.js:7:34)
>       at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (E:\Sublime-Project\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
>       at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (E:\Sublime-Project\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
>       at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (E:\Sublime-Project\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
>       at WebSocket.onMessage (E:\Sublime-Project\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
>       at WebSocket.emit (events.js:197:13) (node:162592) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 85)

Answer (score 1):

I met same error some months ago, please check your relevant Promises. The reason is that you've called a reject function in your promise, but you didn't handle it.